# How can I disable editing content inside a column on my DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I would like to disable editing content inside of my `DataGrid`, for example if user clicks double click he could edit a column right now, and I would like to avoid that...

I tried setting `IsReadOnly` property on my `DataGrid` by writing this:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True">
```

But that is not good for me because I want to delete rows in my `DataGrid` by clicking "Delete" button, and If I set this state to my datagrid

```
IsReadOnly="True"
```

then I'm loosing that functionality...

But  I guess I could somehow apply code below to disable only cells..

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

But unfortunatelly it is not working :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the `IsReadOnly` property of each of the columns to true:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn ... IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This should disable editing of the cells but still let you delete rows.